# Orgasm and Virya

Tags: sexuality, energy

I am aware of Indian spirituality associating orgasm with a loss of energy. This conception is present in other cultures as well.

However, it is conspicuously absent from Western culture. Why isn't there more rigorous evidence of orgasm -- and sexuality in general -- and lack of enthusiasm and vigour? How can one perceive such an association if it exists?

Thank you.

Comment: There is e.g. Christian doctrine on that subject, though: perhaps it's not "conspicuously absent from Western culture" -- see [Concupiscence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concupiscence) for example.

Answer (score 4):

Unless relatively deep/refined samadhi & tranquility have been developed, it is difficult to perceive the loss of energy & loss of mental clarity due to orgasm. Instead, to the undeveloped mind, the temporary relief of organism is something ordinary & normal. This is probably why the Western religious traditions probably don't comment much about orgasm because the true purpose & fruits of celibacy appears to have never been clearly articulated or understood in European Christianity.